# When importing maven project, use <name> instead of <groupid> for project name

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

In eclipse, I do:

- File
- **Import...**
- **Existing Maven Projects**
- **Next**
- I fill **Root Directory**
- Click on **Advanced**

Which variable can I use in **Name Template** section, and more specially which variable corresponds to the `<name>` tag of the pom?

Comment: As far as i know none of them, cause name does not make sense. Better use the defaults or use groupId-artifactId instead.

Comment: If name doesn't make sense, the **Reactor Summary** section of a maven build doesn't make sense too? I don't understand why you say that.

Answer (score 2):

It's an absolutely valid question and you can hardly find any helpful public information. So, taking a look at the source code I figure that:

1. The name template variables (the strings enclosed in square brackets) are those that m2e can try to resolve to values from the project POM file. Anything else is considered as-is without attempts to resolve it.
2. The possible (resolvable) template variables are hard-coded. See this [v1.5 class](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/m2e-1.5.x/org.eclipse.m2e.core/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/project/ProjectImportConfiguration.java) and the logic in the getProjectName method if curious. That is why, for versions prior to 1.6, using `[name]` wouldn't work anyway. The v1.5 valid variables are: `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`. Check the class history for variable support per version
3. Starting with m2e v1.6, there is already a new `[name]` template variable in the same [class](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/m2e-1.6.x/org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/ui/internal/wizards/ResolverConfigurationComponent.java) and getProjectName accounts for it. The full list of supported variables in this version are: `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version` and `name`

The bottom line: there is nothing you can use prior to v 1.5 that will be automatically resolved to the Maven project name. Starting with v 1.6 you can use `[name]`.